# SQL query with restricted keyword in it causing query to not work

Tags: excel, vba, keyword, reserved

I am trying to connect to mdb database through VBA. The code is perfectly fine. If I run the query on any other table , it works perfectly fine. But when I use the table name 'SpeedRestriction', then the query does not return any rows. I tried square brackets , but it does not work. I have only readonly access to the database so changing pre-existing table name is not possible. The code does not give any errors/exceptions.

Is there any workaround? Following is the code.

```
sPath = <Valid path>

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & sPath


conn.Open strConnection

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient

sSql = "Select * from SpeedRestriction"

rs.Open sSql, conn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockPessimistic, adCmdText

Debug.Print rs.EOF
Debug.Print rs.BOF

'XL_Ws_SpeedData.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Speed Data").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

Set rs = Nothing
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
```

Comment: SpeedRestriction isn't a keyword. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe  So are you sure you're connecting to an instance of the database which has data in speedRestriction?  or that the table exists and you're not getting an error?

Comment: SpeedRestriction is not. But Restrict is. Can sql make that distinction? There are 950 records in the table. connection is fine. when I run the query in access it works. But in VBA I don't get records, neither do I get any errors. I tried running the same code with different table names in the query. It works perfectly fine.

Comment: No it can't make that distinction.  the table name is SpeedRestriction.  So something else is going on.  used  debug.print or copy/paste to get the and pasted the sSQL and then tried to run it and it works?  making sure no spelling mistake/Typo on SpeedRestriction

Comment: Perhaps your table is actually named `SpeedRestrictions`? Or there's a typo somewhere? If you copy the query from the VBA code and paste it in Access, does it return rows? **Are you getting any error?**

Comment: If there is any question about the table name, instead of opening using SQL (adCmdText), try opening the table by name (adCmdTable).

Comment: Have you used 'Option Explicit' and compiled all your code? Do you have any error handling involved? Try what @Mat'sMug suggested - it will help pinpoint the issue.

Comment: @Mat'sMug, I tried that. Query works perfectly fine. It is 'SpeedRestriction'. It is not 'SpeedRestrictions'. Following is the result of debug sSql and BOF and EOF --- select * from SpeedRestriction
True
True

Comment: You *still* haven't answered the single fundamental question everybody involved has been asking you: are you getting any error? If so, [edit] your post to include it. If you're not getting any errors, did you by any chance happen to remove an instruction saying `On Error Resume Next` in your code before posting it here?

Comment: Hi @Mat'sMug, no I am not getting any errors. I am not doing any kind of error handling as of now

Comment: Have you tried @WayneG.Dunn's suggestion of opening the table as a table instead of doing `SELECT *`?

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn, as per your suggestions, I tried using following code to retrieve rows from SpeedRestriction table. rs.Open "SpeedRestriction", conn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockPessimistic, adCmdTable
It does not give me any errors. recordcount property returns 0.

Comment: The issue is not with the spelling of table name - you will get an error if table name does not exist (since you have no error trap). Try misspelling the name and see if you get the error. As for your recordcount, since you are opening 'adOpenForwardOnly', the recordcount will not work as you expect. To prove that point, change your statement to 'adOpenStatic' instead of 'adOpenForwardOnly'

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn, you are right. Table name is correct. if I misspell , I get error. Interestingly when I change to adOpenStatic then also recordcount returns zero.                                        ' rs.Open "SpeedRestriction", conn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable                                                                                                Debug.Print rs.EOF
Debug.Print rs.BOF
Debug.Print   rs.RecordCount      '                                                                                      returns True, True , 0

Comment: Since I do not see zero recordcount with your code, I'm slightly puzzled.  For grins, please add a rs.MoveLast  rs.MoveFirst just before the Debug.Print rs.RecordCount.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn, as per your suggestion I added rs.MoveLast just before the debug. It gives me Runtime error 3021-either BOF or EOF is true or the current record has been deleted.

Comment: Then you have zero records returned! You could say "if not rs.eof then rs.movelast rs.movefirst..."

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn, it does not serve my purpose. There are 900+ records in that table. When I run this same code with other tables in the database it works fine. but only for this table, it does not fetch the records. nor does it give any errors/exception.

Comment: If you ger 'rs.eof = true' after the open, then it is returning zero rows. Is there anything 'not simple' about the design of that table? Next I would create a new database, import only that table, open the table, view the records, compact/repair, then run your code against the new database. Or try using DAO to see if that works. There possibly is corruption.

Comment: Hi , I solved this problem. The mdb file was placed in a separate folder than the vba script (But it was valid path on the local laptop). I placed the .mdb file in the same folder as that of vba script and changed the path accordingly in the script. It ran perfectly fine .But I still fail to understand how other tables rows are fetched and only one table gives a problem. It does not make sense to me

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn, Yes I tried witht DAO code today. It worked perfectly fine with the other tables but did not fetch records only from this particular table. I checked the schema for this table.it looks fine. Nothing peculiar.It is a table with 21 fields.Strange :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. The mdb file was placed in a separate folder than the vba script (But it was valid path on the local laptop). I placed the .mdb file in the same folder as that of vba script and changed the path accordingly in the script. It ran perfectly fine .But I still fail to understand how other tables rows are fetched and only one table gives a problem. It does not make sense to me